# java abstract class with generics and inheritance : Bound mismatch

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract

i have 2 abstract classes manipulating generics and 1 factory with generics too. The parent is independent of trips objects and factorize code. The son is based on trips only.

```
//parent
public abstract class AbstractPurchaseExtractor<//
BINDING_CLASS extends ForPnrHandling, //
PURCHASE extends AbstractServicePurchase<?, PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM, COUPON>, //
PRICING extends PricingDefault, //
RECEIPT extends ReceiptDefault, //
ITEM extends AbstractServiceItem<PURCHASE, COUPON>, //
COUPON extends CouponDefault> //
    implements IPurchaseExtractor<BINDING_CLASS, PURCHASE, PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM,     COUPON>
...






//son
public abstract class AbstractTripBasedPurchaseExtractor<//
BINDING_CLASS extends ForPnrHandling, //
TRIP_PURCHASE extends AbstractTripBasedPurchase<?, PRICING, RECEIPT, TRIP_BASED_ITEM,         TRIP_BASED_COUPON> , //
PRICING extends PricingDefault, //
RECEIPT extends ReceiptDefault, //
TRIP_BASED_ITEM extends  AbstractTripBasedItem<TRIP_PURCHASE, TRIP_BASED_COUPON, ?>, //
TRIP_BASED_COUPON extends  TripBasedCouponDefault> //
        extends AbstractPurchaseExtractor<BINDING_CLASS, TRIP_PURCHASE, PRICING,     RECEIPT,     TRIP_BASED_ITEM, TRIP_BASED_COUPON> //
{

@Autowired
private AbstractTripBasedPurchaseFactory<TRIP_PURCHASE, PRICING, RECEIPT, TRIP_BASED_ITEM, TRIP_BASED_COUPON> abstractTripBasedPurchaseFactory;
  ...





//factory
public abstract class AbstractTripBasedPurchaseFactory<PURCHASE extends     AbstractTripBasedPurchase<?, PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM, COUPON>,
                                                   PRICING extends PricingDefault,
                                                   RECEIPT extends ReceiptDefault,
                                                   ITEM extends AbstractTripBasedItem<?     extends AbstractTripBasedPurchase<?, PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM, COUPON>, COUPON, ?>,
                                                   COUPON extends     TripBasedCouponDefault>
   extends AbstractPurchaseFactory<PURCHASE, PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM>
{
```

i have the error on Eclipse for AbstractTripBasedPurchaseExtractor line 9 :
Bound mismatch: The type TRIP_PURCHASE is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

```
<PURCHASE extends AbstractServicePurchase<?,PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM,COUPON>>
```

of the type

```
AbstractPurchaseExtractor<BINDING_CLASS,PURCHASE,PRICING, RECEIPT, ITEM,COUPON>
```

HERE: extends AbstractPurchaseExtractor '< BINDING_CLASS, **TRIP_PURCHASE** ...

using extends on the son class, i need to use for TRIP_PURCHASE something that extends  AbstractServicePurchase. Actually AbstractTripBasedPurchase extends AbstractServicePurchase. So why the error ?

if i replace AbstractTripBasedPurchase  by  AbstractServicePurchase as Eclipse is expecting, of course it compiles but i cannot use my trip factory on the son class.

Comment: That's too many generic types for me to grok right now, but at first glance, having a wildcard (`?`) in there is maybe not so great. Does it help if you replace with it with a type placeholder?

Comment: no, i don't need to replace the wildcard here (?) There is no problem with that. The thing is the extends is expecting me to declare a AbstractServicePurchase class but i pass a son of this class named AbstractTripBasedPurchase. Is weird that is no accepting it, like inheritance is not working

Comment: can you reduce this to a minimal example that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: It sounds weird because it compiles with Maven but my java file is red of errors on Eclipse Kepler ...   Eclipse bug ???

Comment: Holy mother of cows!

Comment: Holy mother of AbstractCowsServices<AbstractCowsFactoryGenericInterface>, please. Back to the problem, the compiler fails to bind `AbstractTripBasedPurchase` to `AbstractServicePurchase` because the types of TRIP_PURCHASE and PURCHASE are potentially unrelated, even if `AbstractServicePurchase` and `AbstractTripBasedPurchase` are.

Comment: i think `AbstractServicePurchase` and `AbstractTripBasedPurchase` are related because `PURCHASE extends AbstractServicePurchase` and `TRIP_PURCHASE extends AbstractTripBasedPurchase` are explicitely declared. I really think is an Eclipse bug :s

Answer (score 0):

The same simplified at maximum.

It works.

```
public interface IGeneric<OBJECT> {
    public void test(OBJECT o);
}


public abstract class Parent<OBJECT extends AbstractProduct> implements IGeneric<OBJECT> {       
}

public abstract class Son<PRODUCT extends Trip> extends Parent<PRODUCT> {
    IService<PRODUCT> service;   
}

public abstract class AbstractProduct {  
}

public class Trip extends AbstractProduct{ 
}

 public interface IService<TRIP extends Trip> { 
}
```

Comment: the classes i use on the first example are based on an API with some inconsistenece hierarchy problems.
Unfortunately, I guess Eclipse doesnt see well inheritance on my case